# Wpf GridView multi-row entry

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm working on a `WPF` application. I need to make a `GridView`. But there is one condition: Each row should be actually two row and first of it contains 3 column. Like:

---

|  cell1  | cell2  | cell3  |

---

|      cell4                |

---

The item class is

```
 Data{string id, string Name, string type, string Path}
```

In this case: path is too long so I should show it on  entire row. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Datagrid with RowDetails always visible, something like:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemSource}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding id}" Header="Id" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Type}" Header="Type" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```